# What is the limit of the quotient of Stieltjes Constants?

Tags: functions, limits

What is the limit :

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{\gamma_{n-1} }{\gamma_{n}} $

Here $\gamma_{n} $ is the [$n$-th Stieltjes Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StieltjesConstants.html).

Comment: I am very sorry to say this, you have posted your question already on MO [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/86299/stieltjes-constant-limit) and also got an answer, I think one should not post a question on MO as well as Math.SE simultaneously ( To reduce redundancy and increase uniqueness in finding something ) . You can opt to post at MO if the question you have asked at Math.SE gets good voting and don't get any answers for many days. I hope you understood. Thank you.

Comment: And if you do post a question to two different sites, it's common courtesy to mention this at both sites, and leave a link to the other site at each site.

Comment: thank you Kannappan Sampath , but the answer on MO wasn't that helpful !!